# Convert JSON response to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, request

I am getting json response from a site

```
response = requests.get(API_URL, params=data)
response_json = response.json()
a = response_json['Time Series (5min)']
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{
   '2021-02-19 18:45:00': {'1. open': '119.1800', '2. high': '119.1800', '3. low': '119.1800', '4. close': '119.1800', '5. volume': '1250'},
   '2021-02-19 18:25:00': {'1. open': '119.1000', '2. high': '119.1000', '3. low': '119.1000', '4. close': '119.1000', '5. volume': '701'} ... }
```

Than i am trying to convert it to dataframe:

```
data = pd.json_normalize(data=a)
print(data)
```

But in the result i have 1 row with lots of columns.
[image: Output]

So how should i convert it to get table with datetime as index and keys in JSON as columns?

Comment: You can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `DataFrame()`
- transpose for shape
- `reindex()` to convert index to date/time

```
a = {'2021-02-19 18:45:00': {'1. open': '119.1800',
  '2. high': '119.1800',
  '3. low': '119.1800',
  '4. close': '119.1800',
  '5. volume': '1250'},
 '2021-02-19 18:25:00': {'1. open': '119.1000',
  '2. high': '119.1000',
  '3. low': '119.1000',
  '4. close': '119.1000',
  '5. volume': '701'}}


df = pd.DataFrame(a).T
df.reindex(pd.to_datetime(df.index))
```

|  | 1. open | 2. high | 3. low | 4. close | 5. volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-19 18: 45: 00 | 119.18 | 119.18 | 119.18 | 119.18 | 1250 |
| 2021-02-19 18: 25: 00 | 119.1 | 119.1 | 119.1 | 119.1 | 701 |